# How to properly manage external dependencies in prefect flow?

Tags: python, docker, modulenotfounderror, orchestration, prefect

I would like to implement one central prefect project, where over time it will be possible to add flows independent of each other. The structure of the project is something like this:

```
prefect/
├── src/
│   ├── flows/
│   │   ├── test_pack1/
│   │   │   ├── common/
│   │   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   │   └── test_module.py
│   │   │   ├── .env
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── requirements.txt
│   │   │   └── test_pack1_flow.py
│   │   ├── test_pack2/
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── .env
│   │   │   ├── requirements.txt
│   │   │   └── test_pack2_flow.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── Dockerfile
│   ├── utilities/
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── storage.py
│   │   ├── builder.py
│   │   ├── executor.py
│   │   └── run_config.py
│   ├── .env
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── main.py
├── .gitignore
├── poetry.lock
└── pyproject.toml
```

I would like each flow in the `flows/` folder to be independent of the central project and created as a separate docker container.

`builder.py` at startup searches for all flows in `flows/` folder, sets a specific configuration and registers them on the server.

But I ran into the problem of importing third-party packages. Let's say in the `test_package1/` in `requirements.txt` there is `SQLAlchemy==1.4.34`. And in `test_pack1/common/test_module.py` there is an `import sqlalchemy`. And `test_pack1/test_pack1_flow.py` have a `@task` with function from `test_module.py`. When the FlowBuilder class looks for a `flow` variable in the file `test_pack1_flow.py` it does this using the function `flow = extract_flow_from_file(str(flow_module))`. At this step, a `ModuleNotFoundError` error occurs, since there is no such dependency in the prefect central application(in `pyproject.toml`). But when the docker container is created, after `flow.register()`, of course it will already be there. How can I handle this step? Or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

I use Docker Storage, Docker Run and Local Executor.

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of packaging flow code dependencies, and it's all definitely doable. Since this was cross-posted on Prefect Discourse [here](https://discourse.prefect.io/t/how-to-properly-manage-external-dependencies-in-prefect-flow/718/2), I responded in much more detail there.

Here is a short summary:

- You can use Prefect Register CLI instead of building custom builder.py functionality looping over flows
- You can have a custom utility function setting different storage and run_config based on your environment (dev/stage/prod etc)
- To solve the problem of dependencies being in a Docker image but not in your local environment, you can solve it with a custom package defined with `setup.py`